# AngularJS, JSON, and js restrictions. How read a JSON file from outside with $http.get and "file:///" URI?

Tags: json, angularjs, http, get

Is there any known and consolidated alternative for defining a new Angular scope reading data from outside?
I am working on a demo that should make available a standalone html page which reads the data from the same html file position, and on client machines without any webserver.
This because the HTML is generated on the fly from a pdf.
Do you have any idea?

In my working code below I should change $http.get('data.json'.. to avoid the Google restriction (on Firefox my sample is working fine).

```
<script>
    var isisApp = angular.module('isisApp', []);
    isisApp.controller('ISISListCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('data.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.IsisDocument = data;
    etc.....
```

and this is the error I get from Chrome:
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/temp/data.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP. angular.js:8081
Error: A network error occurred.

Thanks in advance
Fabio

Answer (score 2):

If you want to test your code, while developing, you have two options:

- Use a local web server. You could use [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) platform, using [expressjs](http://expressjs.com/).
- Start Chrome from the terminal with the `–allow-file-access-from-files` option